# Is there have any option for Indexing mongodb with django in pycharm

Tags: django, mongodb, pycharm

I am trying to indexing on some of the fields in MongoDB collection and I am making model in django. I made a model, but I don't know how can we use indexing while creating a model

## Indexing on mongodb with django

```
class USERCHAT(models.Model):
_id = models.ObjectIdField()
SenderID = models.CharField(max_length=255, db_index=True)
ReceiverID = models.CharField(max_length=255, db_index=True)
Message = models.CharField(max_length=255)
DateTime = models.DateTimeField()
objects = models.DjongoManager()
```

guide me for doing indexing.

```
Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 3.0.5
```

Database
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
'default': {
'ENGINE': 'djongo',
'NAME': "MTR",
}
}

Comment: Which Package are you using to connect to the MongoDB? 
Please add the DATABASES definition from your settings.py.

Comment: DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'djongo',
        'NAME': "MTR",
    }
}